# Nice lemma regarding factorials and quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

**IMPORTANT**: I posted this as I thought I found a generalized result, which turned out to be false (by a trivial flaw), but a nice lemma still remains (however, this can be closed now)

Lemma:

> If $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, then
> $$\bigg(\frac{(\frac{p-1}{4})!}{p}\bigg)=-1$$

This problem below appeared in a USA contest (I think) some time ago:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p=8k+1$. Suppose that $$\binom{4k}{k}\equiv r\pmod{p}$$ Prove that $\sqrt{r}$ is not an integer.

Now this is actually true (By the way, try the problem yourself, it is very beautiful). So under this assumptioin, lets prove the lemma

**Proof:**

When $v_2(p-1)=3$

This gives us $p\equiv 9\pmod{16}\Rightarrow p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$. Lets write $p=8k+1$. So by the above problem i just stated, we get:

$$\bigg(\frac{\binom{4k}{k}}{p}\bigg)=-1$$

Lets start interpreting this:

$$\bigg(\frac{\binom{4k}{k}}{p}\bigg)=-1\Leftrightarrow \bigg(\frac{(4k)!}{p}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{k!\cdot(3k)!}}{p}\bigg)$$

Notice that

$$1=\bigg(\frac{1}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{k!\cdot(3k)!}}{p}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{k!\cdot(3k)!}{p}\bigg)$$

so $$\bigg(\frac{k!\cdot(3k)!}{p}\bigg)=\frac{1}{\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{k!\cdot(3k)!}}{p}\bigg)}=\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{k!\cdot(3k)!}}{p}\bigg)$$

Thus, substituting in

$$\bigg(\frac{(4k)!}{p}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{k!\cdot(3k)!}}{p}\bigg)$$

we have

$$\bigg(\frac{(4k)!}{p}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{k!\cdot(3k)!}{p}\bigg)\Leftrightarrow\bigg(\frac{(3k)!}{p}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{(3k+1)(3k+2)...4k}{p}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{(3k)!}{p}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{k!}{p}\bigg)$$

so we get

$$\bigg(\frac{(3k+1)(3k+2)...4k}{p}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{k!}{p}\bigg)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\big((3k+1)(3k+2)...4k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv-\big(k!\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

Multiplying both sides by $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$, we have:

$$\big((6k+2)(6k+4)...8k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv-\big(2\cdot4\cdot6...\cdot2k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

But

$$\big((6k+2)(6k+4)...8k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv\big(-(2k-1)\cdot-(2k-3)...\cdot-1\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \big( (-1)^k\cdot1\cdot3...\cdot(2k-1)\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

$\frac{p-1}{2}=4k$, so

$$\big( (-1)^k\cdot1\cdot3...\cdot(2k-1)\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv\big(1\cdot3...\cdot(2k-1)\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

Substituting in

$$\big((6k+2)(6k+4)...8k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv-\big(2\cdot4\cdot6...\cdot2k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

we get the following:

$$\big(1\cdot3...\cdot(2k-1)\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv-\big(2\cdot4\cdot6...\cdot2k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$

Finally, by multiplying both sides by $\big(2\cdot4\cdot6...\cdot2k\big)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$, we get:

$$(2k)!\equiv-1\big(2\cdot4\cdot6...\cdot2k\big)^{p-1}\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$

So we have

$$\bigg(\frac{(\frac{p-1}{4})!}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{(2k)!}{p}\bigg)=-1$$

Which is exactly what we wanted to prove.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't any Fermat prime $p = 2^{2^n} + 1$ for $n \ge 2$ be a counterexample?

We have $$\frac {p-1}{2^{v_2(p-1)-1}} = \frac {2^{2^n}}{2^{2^n-1}}=2$$

To find $\left(\dfrac{2!}p\right)$ we use the Second Supplement to Law of Quadratic Reciprocity:

$$p \equiv 1 \pmod 8 \implies \left(\frac2p\right) = 1$$

Indeed the smallest counterexample (should be) $17$, where $2 \equiv 6^2 \pmod {17}$.

Comment: Yes, there is an error. I think that the greatest value it works for is $\bigg(\frac{\big(\frac{p-1}{4}\big)!}{p}\bigg)$